# R Error in gvisCheckOrgChartData(data, my.options) :

Tags: r, googlevis

I am trying to build a collapsable Org Charts through gvisOrgChart for a very simply data but there is a constant error of gvisCheckOrgChartDat (data, my.options) : parentvar and idvar do not fit together.

I have three columns Employee ID, Employee and Manager

Emp ID is from 1 to 13 all unique 
Emp Names are from A to M all unique 
Manager column is NA, M, N, O,M, N, O,M, N, O,M, N, O

```
VBS= read.csv("OrgCharts/VBS.csv")
data.frame("VBS")
View(VBS)
VBS$Employee = as.factor(VBS$Employee)
VBS$Manager = as.factor(VBS$Manager)

VBSOrg =  gvisOrgChart(VBS, idvar = "Employee", parentvar = "Manager", options=list(width=600, height=400,size='small', allowCollapse=TRUE))
plot(VBSOrg)
```

I want to get a simple org chart like the one in the Regions (gvisOrgChart) example

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I figured out the issue.

Thee issue was that i had nodes in parentvar filed that were not part of idvar field.This was leading to ngation of "only root allowed". Essentiall my data had multiple roots which is not allowed.

Is there a way through which we can have multiple root org charts, also i want to color ceetain node based on a conditiion

Answer (score 0):

```
parentvar and idvar do not fit together.
```

Hi, this is saying "the order of managers and subordinates don't align".

Try this pattern instead: `ManID=as.factor(c(NA, "A", "B", "C","B", "C", "B","C", "B", "C","B", "C", "B"))`.